# OpenCl work groups

Tags: opencl

What happens when I for example set my amount of

1. workgroups to 5120 and localsize 1
2. workgroups to 2560 and localsize 2
3. workgroups to 640 and localsize 4

How does this influence my amount of work-items and access to resources ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You will have `5120 threads. 5120 groups. 1 thread per group`. Each Group(1 thread) will take one processor. You can't synchronize any of them (in the traditional sense).
2. You will have `2560 threads. 1280 groups. 2 threads in each group`. Each Group(2 threads) will take one processor. You can synchronize these two threads(in the traditional sense).
3. You will have `640 threads. 160 groups. 4 threads in each group`. Each Group(4 threads) will take one processor. You can synchronize these four threads(in the traditional sense).

In OpenCL you need to express the global Work Size in terms of the total number of threads. The underlying OpenCL API will look at the global Work Size and divide by the local Work Size to figure out your thread arrangement.

Now (this is a general suggestion. There might be cases where you need to do it, but for now ..)

1. Is a terrible idea. Clearly. You are wasting your processors time by giving it 1 thread at a time. While this might not to be the end of the world for CPUs it is for modern GPUs. Why? because each processor on your GPU will have a number of cores. All ready for action. Only one of them works in this case. Plus You have no way of synchronizing threads if the need arises.
2. Same thing.
3. Same thing.

If I remember correctly NVIDIA suggests at least 32 threads in a group to get the best performance.